# How to extract environment variables in Rancher automatically

Tags: automation, build-automation, rancher

First of all, sorry if this thread is not appropiated in Stack Overflow, but I think that is the best place of all.

We are using Rancher to manage a microservices solution. Most of the containers are NodeJS + Express apps, but there are others like Mongo or Identity Server.

We use many environment variables like endpoints or environment constants and, when we upgrade some of the containers individually, we forget to include them (most of the times, the person who deploys an upgrade is not the person who made the new version).

So, we're looking a way to manage them. We know that using a Dockerfile could be the best way, but if we need to upgrade just one container, we think that is too many work for just a minor change.

**TLDR;** How do you manage your enviromental variables in Rancher? How do you document them or how you extract them automatically?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure this is appropriate for SO. There are uservices questions you could research over on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com tohugh I'm not sure that would apply either. At the end of the day, SO is more about specific coding questions.

Comment: I know @jdv, but as you say, software engineering I think its' not the best forum either...

Answer (score 0):

Applications in Rancher are generally managed using Stacks/Services. Dockerfile is used to build a container image. docker-compose/rancher-compose files are used to define the applications. The environment variables can be specified in docker-compose file.

When you upgrade a service in rancher, the environment variables information is carried forward and also it's possible to edit them before upgrade.

Also Rancher "Catalog" feature might be something useful for you. Checkout: https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v1.6/en/catalog/